# Синхронные HTTP запросы

Tags: .net, http

Есть ли в .Net синхронные HTTP запросы? И стоит ли их использовать (из консольного приложения)?

Comment: Можно использовать `HttpClient` в синхронном коде, да: `using (var client = new HttpClient()) { var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result; }` Но это заморожет приложение, пока `client` не возвращает результат.

Comment: @PeterOlson это мне и нужно, пока я с async лучше не разобрался. Просто дописывать в любой асинхронний метор .Result и оно дождется конца выполнения?

Comment: Да, можно тоже использовать `.Wait()`. Но я бы рекомендовал разобраться с `Async`.

Comment: @PeterOlson а с ним можно например делать запросы в 10 потоков?

Comment: Скорее всего можно, я не уверен, но если вы хотите отправить 10 запросы одновременно, то имхо будет намного легче асинхронным образом.

Comment: @PeterOlson мне нужно ограничение в x параллельных запросов.

Comment: @PeterOlson нужен ли .Wait() или достаточно .Result?

Comment: `.Result` достаточно

Comment: Чтобы задать число потоков для обращения к серверу, можно воспользоваться классом `System.Net.ServicePointManager`

Comment: В таком случае можно хоть все запросы начать одновременно - но больше указанного числа запросов одновременно к серверу не уйдет.